# How to change site scroll speed?

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll

I change my sites' theme and have a problem with scrolling, the scrolling speed is very slow especially in Chrome Browser. I try to solve the problem with this jQuery plugin:
[jQuery.scrollSpeed](https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed)

I have added the plugin file in the header after jQuery and added a function at the end of the body tag. This is the function:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        jquery.scrollSpeed(300, 800);
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working. Any idea how to make the plugin work OR better than that help to solve the site scroll problem?

I have removed two .js files that have "scroll" world in their name from the theme folder, but it doesn't make any changes.

My site address is:  [www.javaherlux.com](https://www.javaherlux.com)

Comment: There is **never** an acceptable reason to change scroll speed. Don't do it. Seriously.

Comment: @Veedrac Thank You for your advise but did you check my site? current situation is a nightmare that i stuck in it. Can you Help me plsss

Comment: Yes, your site is a nightmare. The solution is disabling whatever Javascript you're running, which is obviously broken.